# How I filling featured image of posts in wordpress automatically by php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I receiving a posts data as a variables in my php site like this :

```
$$post_title ="post title"
post_content ="post content"
post_slug = "post slug"
$post_category = "post_ ategory"
$featured_image = "post featured image URL"
```

and I think no problem to send this variables to my mysql wordpress tables **(wp_posts , wp_term_relationships & wp_term_taxonomy**)
I did not try it yet, but I think it's easy

My question here about **$featured_image** .How I send it to my mysql table to be the featured image of this post and do I have to upload the image from the URL to  my site host or what's the steps ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );
```

where 1st argument is post id while second argument is thumbnail id ... for more details visit official WordPress codex page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail